# Pause video recording and Resume in React Native

Tags: react-native, camera, expo, recording

I am trying to create a video recording application with Expo react native, I am using Camera library but I can't find a function or method for pausing/resuming the video recording,
Given there are a lot of applications out there that have this functionality is it safe to say it is a react native restriction and there is no built-in support for this functionality in react native?

Answer (score 0):

So far, You can't pause and resume video recording with React native. Most of the app out there save the videos in array and then Merge them to a single file. I am very sure that both Instagram and tiktok uses this method.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but merging videos on a mobile device is slow isn't it? how do they do it so fast?

Comment: You use Fluent-FFMPEG on nodejs. You upload the two videos and send it to nodejs then you can compress it on the server for data reduction